# Winsorize data by group with data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a dataset as below:

```
dt <- fread("    ID  Year  POP     REV
A   1970  13116   3829
  A   1971  13116   4020
  B   1972    110      0
  C   1972    870     17
  D   1972    500     20
  D   1972    300     10", header = T)

ID  Year  POP     REV
A   1970  13116   3829
A   1971  13116   4020
B   1972    110      0
C   1972    870     17
D   1972    500     20
D   1972    300     10
```

I know there is a function `Winsorize()` to do such thing.
However, I don't know how to winsorize by `Year`.
The code I operate `winsorize()` as below:

```
winsorize(dt$POP, minval = quantile(dt$POP, 0.01), maxval = quantile(dt$POP, 0.99), probs = c(0.01, 0.99))
[1] 2108.296 2108.296  110.000  870.000  500.000  300.000
```

Any solution on how to do this with package `data.table`?

Comment: Try `dt[, newval := winsorize(POP, minval = quantile(POP, 0.01), maxval = quantile(POP, 0.95), probs = c(0.01, 0.99)), by = Year]`  Is the function from `robustHD` package or from `DescTools` (in that case, it is `Winsorize`

Comment: sorry for my ignorance. function is from `robustHD`. However, which one is better?

Comment: If it is from `robustHD`, then the parameters are [different](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/robustHD/versions/0.5.1/topics/winsorize).  I haven't used it, so not sure about which one is better

Comment: @akrun I try to find out what is `probs = c(0.01, 0.99)`, why do I include this? Can you explain about this? In some cases, after winsorizing from `DescTools`, the maximum value seems weird.